# Thrift Async Client will not stop

Tags: java, asynchronous, thrift

I wonder why without the code remarked as `1`, even the result is not `null`, the application keeps running and never stop, and the code remarked as `2` doesn't print the expected result.

But with the code remarked as `1`, the application finishes when the result is not `null`,and prints the code which remarked as `2`.

AsyncMethodCallback

```
private Object response=null;

public Object getResponse() {
    return response;
}

@Override
public void onComplete(Object response) {
    this.response=response;
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Async Server

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TNonblockingServerSocket serverSocket=new TNonblockingServerSocket(10005);
        Hello.Processor<Hello.Iface> processor=new Hello.Processor<>(new HelloServiceImpl());
        TNonblockingServer.Args serverArgs=new TNonblockingServer.Args(serverSocket);
        TProtocolFactory factory=new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
        serverArgs.transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory());
        serverArgs.processor(processor);
        serverArgs.protocolFactory(factory);
        TServer server=new TNonblockingServer(serverArgs);
        System.out.println("server start....");
        server.serve();

    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Async Client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TAsyncClientManager clientManager=new TAsyncClientManager();
        TNonblockingSocket socket=new TNonblockingSocket("localhost",10005);
        TProtocolFactory protocolFactory=new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
        Hello.AsyncClient asyncClient=new Hello.AsyncClient(protocolFactory,clientManager,socket);
        System.out.println("Client calls....");
        MethodCallback<Integer> methodCallback=new MethodCallback<>();
        asyncClient.helloInt(14,methodCallback);
        Object result=methodCallback.getResponse();
        while (result==null){
            result=methodCallback.getResponse();
            // System.out.println("result is "+result); //1
        }
        System.out.println(result); //2

    } catch (IOException | TException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```